# Different JSON responses - {"count":"123"} vs {"count"=>"123"}

Tags: php, ruby, json

I have some PHP code which queries a MySQL database for a count.

When queried via a browser I get the following output:

```
{"count":"123"}
```

I also have a Ruby script which executes the same PHP script via Net::HTTP but the output is different:

```
{"count"=>"123"}
```

Why is this?

```
//The URL
uri = URI.parse("http://lab/count.php")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
//Request URL
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
//Basic authentication
request.basic_auth("user1", "secret")
response = http.request(request)
//Response
response = JSON.parse(response.body)
puts results
//Value 'count'
count = JSON.parse(response.body)[0]
puts count
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{"count"=>"123"}` is not JSON response.

It's ruby literal for Hash table.

I think you are seeing the result of parsed JSON:

```
>> require 'json'
>> JSON.parse('{"count":"123"}') # => {"count"=>"123"}
>> puts JSON.dump({"count"=>"123"}) # prints => {"count":"123"}
```

---

**UPDATE** response to comment

To get `123` printed.

```
uri = URI.parse("http://lab/count.php")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth("user1", "secret")
response = http.request(request)
response = JSON.parse(response.body)
puts response['count']
```

Comment: @pablo808, Actually you don't need to parse JSON. Remove json-parsing part from your ruby script.

Comment: Thanks. How can print the value "123" only.

Comment: @pablo808, Could you post the code again. (not in comment, but in your question)